# Homepage can be loaded but on others - "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: server, apache2, wordpress

I tried putting on a server some sort of site using Apache/2.4.29 (WordPress and stuff), but no page aside from the homepage itself can be loaded.
I'm given an "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu). Server at localhost Port 8080" error while accessing those pages. What can be the root of the problem and what should I do? I'm brand-new to all this stuff, so sorry if I've asked anything too stupid.

I've changed in `apache2.conf` `AllowOverride` and that's it.

```
 </Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What exactly are the steps and or commands you are using to try and get to the pages that give the error?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing an `.htaccess` file ...